# Do I mandatory add views in UIScrollView in order to scroll those views?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have used auto layout and after designing screen I need to scroll all the contents. If I add all the screen views inside a new scrollview, all my constraints will not work. So whats the easiest way doing this?

Comment: have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The Easy way is ,

Take One **scrollview** in **Mainview** then add **another view(Contentview)** in **scrollview** and then **add all the content** in content view. so, you can able to scroll contentview. and when your contentview will be scroll then all control will goes up and down. Due to contnent view.

Your hierarchy will be something like this ,

```
Mainview 
  Scrollview
     ContentView
              Textfield
              button 
              Label
```

[image]

On below link , You will find best tutorial regarding

[Set Constrain to Scrollview with Autolayout with Example](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)

and last but not the lease ,

Don't forget to untick **Adjust Scrollview insets** in viewcontroller property.

[image]